# Back button is stuck when loading webview in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

1. I have presented the webview but I press back button view controller is not dismissed.
2. When I put beakpoint on my cancel button.Its is not triggered.

Here is my code:

```
 //MARK: - View Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       loadWebView()
    }

    //MARK: - Methods
    func loadWebView() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.lipsum.com/")
            //(URL(string: Constant.MedataApi.BaseUrl)?.appendingPathComponent(Constant.termsAndConditions))!
        let request = NSURLRequest.init(url: url! as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
        //webView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        //webView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    }

//MARK: - IBActions () -        

    @IBAction func cancelButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you comment    `loadWebView()` in `viewDidLoad()` and then press back button, still it works?

Comment: are you using `push` or `modal` to goto `webView` controller?

Comment: how about loading url asynchronically???

Comment: the button action is called or not, show the view hierarchy of your class

Comment: are you push or present for moving on  viewcontroller

Comment: Make sure that the `IBAction` is connected to the button at Storyboard.

Comment: webview load successfully but when i click on back button it is not clickable.Cancel button is in hierarchy ... I am using  present model

Comment: if I comment the loadwebview part the code then my cancel button is working fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose you have two View Controller, one is FirstViewController and the the other is SecondViewController(webView).
2. In Main.storyboard, select the FirstViewController and embed it as a NavigationController.
3. Now assign a Storyboard ID to SecondViewController in Main.storyboard, suppose Storyboard ID is "SecondVC".
4. In FirstViewController.swift add the code for button action:

   `let firstController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondViewController`

   `navigationController?.pushViewController(firstController, animated: true)`
5. Then add the webView code in SecondViewController.swift file.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

   let url = URL(string: "http://www.lipsum.com/")
   let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
   webView.loadRequest(request)
   webView.scalesPageToFit = true
   }
   ```

Comment: webview loads its content but cancel button is stuck. When i comment my code of loading webview its working fine..

Comment: did you try to add the code in viewDidLoad() function? Did you override it? Because adding code in loadView() and viewDidLoad() matters.